# Eigenvalues of a matrix with all diagonal elements zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

Hi I want to check if the following matrix has any  eigenvalues with positive real part
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \displaystyle\frac{b_3 (J_3-J_2) k_p}{J_1} & \displaystyle\frac{b_2 (J_3-J_2) k_p}{J_1} \\
 \displaystyle\frac{b_3 (J_1-J_3) k_p}{J_2} & 0 & \displaystyle\frac{b_1 (J_1-J_3) k_p}{J_2} \\
 \displaystyle\frac{b_2 (J_2-J_1) k_p}{J_3} & \displaystyle\frac{b_1 (J_2-J_1) k_p}{J_3} & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that $||b||=1$ and $J_1>0$, $J_2>0$ and $J_3>0$.

PS: determinant of the matrix is $\dfrac{-2*b_1*b_2*b_3*(J_1-J_2)(J_3-J_1)(J_2-J_3)k_p^3}{J_1J_2J_3}$

Comment: Trace is zero, If the matrix is not skew symmetric (or zero matrix) then there should be at-least one eigenvalue with positive real. Is this true?

Comment: In response to your comment, the sum of the eigenvalues is $0$. Thus, if they're all real and not all $0$, at least one must be positive. But what about eigenvalues like $-2$, $1+i$, $1-i$? So something like $\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: It does not always possess a positive eigenvalue. E.g. when $k_p=1,\ (J_1,J_2,J_3)=(1,2,3)$ and $b=(3,3,1)/\sqrt{19}$, the matrix has one negative eigenvalue and two non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: I am sorry, it should have been 'eigenvalues with positive real part' instead of 'positive real eigenvalues'

Answer (score 1):

The matrix does not always possess an eigenvalue with a positive real part. E.g. it is nilpotent when $b_3=0$ and $J_1=J_2$.